# Reset View after leaving it - SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I need to reset my Search-view on Button Click. That means when I leave the view through the "close"-Button and go back to the search, it is supposed to be reloaded:

- Inputs empty
- Result-table hidden
- as if it is reloaded

I just cant make sure to reload the view because once it is called, its saved in the Core and cant be deleted, without being unable to get it again.

Right now I am setting the Visibility to false and true to open or close the view, but I cant find the magic code here!^^

Here is what happens when I press the close Button:

```
handleSchliessen : function () {
        var p = this.getView('suche');
        p.setVisible(false);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("Handler").getModel("datenModel").refresh(true);
        this.callbackMethod.call(this.callbackObject);
    },
```

Any help would be great guys, I can provide more Code if you need, its just too long :)

Comment: add screenshot of the UI, I am unable to understand your requirement completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My normal approach is to bind everything to a model (visibility result table, results, input fields) and set these model properties back to their initial state when done.

For instance,

```
var initState = {
    tblVisible : false,
    searchResults : [],
    input : ""
}

oModel.setProperty("/path/to/searchview/properties", initState);
```

Comment: Where would you implement this? And what is tblVisible? Is it an object in the model?

Comment: When you press the close button, in your controller. `tblVisible` is just some arbitrary property I created where you store a boolean so you can bind to your table's `visible` property

Comment: I now get the Problem, that the Model will be loaded after the view is loaded. Its weird. When I put a breakpoint at the table and looked for the model. it wasnt loaded yet. Why wouldnt it be loaded with the oninit method?

Comment: `onInit` is triggered only once, when the view is instantiated. `onBefore/AfterRendering` are generally better places for recurring view action